# What is the maximum distance darkvision you can get without magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, vision-and-light

You are in the Underdark and need to see as far as you can to scout for your party: 
What is the maximum distance that you can see, using darkvision, without magic or magical items?

Comment: Is this for any race/class combo? Or do you want to know something specific for a character you have? When you say "No Magic", do you also mean "No magic items"? So just inherent race/class abilities? What level will you be?

Comment: Are you wondering how to extend all sight distance or just darkvision? You say in your body "what is the max you can see" but that doesn't actually limit the answers to just darkvision. Are you just asking how far you can extend darvision without magic? Or do you want to know how far you can see with any ability in the dark without magic?

Comment: And does "without magic" specifically actually mean without using spells, or are you ruling out any kind of ability which is described as magical (e.g. certain class features)?

Comment: Most importantly - welcome! Please take our [tour] to learn a bit more about the stack :) Please don't take offense to the votes to hold, we just want to make sure we give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Does that edit that was just made to your question mean what you were trying to say? If not, please [edit] and clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 8):

## 150 ft.

First, pick a race with Superior Darkvision, such as the drow (PHB, p. 24) or deep gnome (MToF, p. 114). That sees you at 120 ft. already.

> ***Superior Darkvision.*** Your darkvision has a radius of 120 feet.

Then, pick a class archetype that grants you darkvision in such a way that it extends your range, such as the Gloom Stalker ranger archetype (XGtE, p. 42).

> ***Umbral Sight.*** At 3rd level, you gain darkvision out to a range of 60 feet. If you already have darkvision from your race, its range increases by 30 feet.

Comment: Ninja'd by a minute. +1

Comment: @KorvinStarmast me too.

Comment: @NautArch well there's technically two (the normal one and the revised one).

Comment: @MrHiTech Are you referring to UA and XGTE, or something else?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yes those.